# angular material and md-icon directives

Tags: css, icons, angular-material

I've several issues with the md-icon directive (from angular-material).
Here is the code which shows my problems : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpWNWr

Here is the important part of the HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <div layout="row">
    <span class="noselect" ng-repeat="rates in rating track by $index" >
      <md-icon class="stars noselect" >
        {{rates.icon}}
      </md-icon>
    </span>
    {{rate}}
  </div>
</div>
```

the css

```
.stars {
    font-size: 36px !important;
    margin-right: 12px;
}

.noselect {
  outline: none;
}
```

and the js :

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']);

myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.rating = [];

  $scope.rating.push({icon: "star"});
  $scope.rating.push({icon: "star"});
  $scope.rating.push({icon: "star_half"});
  $scope.rating.push({icon: "star_border"});
  $scope.rating.push({icon: "star_border"});

  $scope.rate = 2.5;
});
```

So in this code, some problems :

- Why have I to set the size of the icon with `!important` and set the margin manually after ? Is there a solution to set the margin automatically depending of the size of the icon ?
- How can an align my text with the icons ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things I need to clear. For your 1st question you don't need to use `!important` and if you want a specify margin then only use specify margin in that way otherwise use `layout-margin` attribute on container or for padding use `layout-padding`. Now the [offical documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/api/directive/mdIcon) says that we can use `font-icon` of size `24px` `32px` `40px` `48px` by using `md-24` `md-32` `md-40` and `md-48` calls with the help of `material-icons` this class. But in reality I am not able to use it so you have to manually specify in your css file. There is an [issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3036) I found on GitHub too.So in the below link I defined those class with the example.

Now to align you elements you can use `layout-align="start center` it will align all elements in center in vertical direction. Cheke the [offical doc](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/layout/alignment) for other cool options. So just check the below link and let me know if anything is missing.

http://codepen.io/next1/pen/GZmJRM

One thing to remember as since you are using `material-design` all your dimentations should be a multiple of 8. So if possible try not to use `36px` kind of value.